# postgreSQL(Centos7, Vultr) keep loses its all schema

Tags: sql, node.js, linux, postgresql, centos7

PostgreSQL on CentOS7(Vultr) keep losing all its data by itself.
It just deletes all of its data in a matter of minutes after I create table and insert some row into it.
All of its database, table, rows are deleted. *The changes are accessible for just few minutes.

Any idea why does this keep happening?

I'm using `root` role and default setting, since creating another role doesn't work quite right,
and I run pg-promise(node.js postgresql library), node.js
but haven't run any 'drop table' command from it.
It didn't run into any 'everything is gone' situation at other testbeds.
It just works fine from local computer/heroku.

Comment: Have you make a `commit` at the end of the sql request ? (even if for DB this should not happen)

Comment: Why and how do I `commit`? it didn't require any commit from my local computers and heroku. I've been creating heroku apps for months and haven't required to `commit` Does PosgreSQL works differently from Linux? I can't find any related article from Google.

Comment: Sorry for all the broken English and grammars...I am in a hurry now. Why local computers and heroku don't require `commit`? any changes that I have made stay fine there Heroku/PC  but why not on Linux(Vultr) server? are there any sort of preparations that I must do, other than just install and run the DB?

Comment: `Commit` is a SQL keyword to write your change when you make INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE statement in a not auto-commit session.  I think you're mixing the DB instance and the OS. Are you sure your DB is missing ?

Comment: oh, then...is there an option to make the all `commit` automatic? are those turned on by default from Windows pc and Heroku?

Comment: welp, I just found about 'autocommit' features from Google. I'll be back after a test session. Frankly I am surprised because no webdev books/lessons have told me about this when they teach me about writing CRUD apps.

Comment: I deserve downvote for this one but I've just found out that there was a typo in my db name at server side, I had databases with similar name but slightly different structure. This was the source of problem. It didn't happen on my desktop and heroku because the server setting was right from there. I just renamed the tables and databases and it works fine. Also `commit` is not really necessary. PostgreSQL always autocommits by default. Moreover, since I am using a 3rd party library, it automatically commits every changes.

Comment: ok, better that way then, because I was a bit short on idea... ;)